# Why do some chemical reactions lead to less stable state?

Tags: enthalpy, entropy

If the universe is always trying to find a more stable energy state, then how do reactions take place that lead to a less stable state e.g. the formation of ammonia from extremely stable diatomic $\ce{N2}$ molecules?

Comment: Thermodynamics doesn't say that an "unfavorable reaction" can't take place. Thermodynamics says that if an unfavorable reaction takes place then it takes energy input. See http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp209795t The "lighting bolt" on the reaction arrow in the diagram is a photon supplying the energy.

Comment: You have to consider the entire system to see whether a reaction is favorable. It is true that exothermic reactions lead to more "stable" products. But there are other factors that are in place. Pressure, heat, and work. Later on you will learn how these come into the picture. But for now, your understanding of stability seems to only encompass the energy of the bonds of the products. But that is not the case.  Also, you are wrong about the Haber process being endothermic. It is not.

Comment: @user97554 I have edited my answer accordingly. And thank you MaxW for the link. As I am currently teaching myself (not attending an courses on the subject), are there any wiki pages or reading material that you'd recommend that might expand my view to encompass variables like pressure, heat, and work? Thanks

Comment: @user3256725 - not having any idea of your level of understanding I wouldn't know what to recommend. I will say that thermodynamics is one of the last areas to study.